# ASP.NET MVC form engine for an intranet solution?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there one that's worth looking into as an intranet solution ? The only one i've found that's even half decent is 
[Survey](http://survey.codeplex.com/).

Reasons i don't want to use it is i would prefer ASP.NET MVC over Webforms and the project above has given me many headaches starting from security issues (for example last time i checked, HTML injection was allowed by default) and ending with the usability of the solution from an end user perspective. 
The form engine's user interface and usability is just not acceptable for the problem i'm trying to solve.

I was very impressed with the Java based form engine called [Orbeon](http://www.orbeon.com/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/new). Is there anything like that for ASP.NET MVC ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Orchard CMS. It is the best for .net MVC and people from Microsoft are involved though not a official Microsoft project. It is highly extensible.

http://www.orchardproject.net/